# Remove CR (\r) while reading text file

Tags: bash

I have this script where I'm reading a text file line by line and executing a command. I found that the strings (aka lines) always ends with `'\r'`.

I wanna remove the CR from the end of the string.

This is how my code looks like:

```
file="myfilelist.txt"

while IFS= read -r filename
do

git log --oneline -- ${filename} |wc -l

done <"$file"
```

I wanna be able to perform the command in the loop without `\r` at the end of every line string (aka filename).

Comment: The usual way to indicate that an answer solved your problem is to accept it by clicking the checkmark.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
git log --oneline -- $(echo "$filename" | tr -d '\r') | wc -l
```

Note that you don't need the curly braces when `$filename` is surrounded by whitespace.

In principle you can also do this via bash's own parameter expansion mechanism:

```
git log --oneline -- ${filename%^M} | wc -l
```

but the `^M` has to be a literal control-M character, which is ugly and difficult to maintain.

Or you can delete all whitespace characters at the end of the name (which includes `^M` as well as space, tab, et al):

```
git log --oneline -- ${filename%[-[:space:]]} | wc -l
```

But now we're getting into techniques that very few people are likely to recognize without reading [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html#Pattern-Matching).

Comment: I always forget about tr .. must try harder freudy!

Comment: @user1564015: Please don't do that. By removing the code you were having problems with, you make it more difficult for others to figure out what's going on. I'm going to revert your edit, putting the question back the way it was.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Will make sure not to do so in the future!

Comment: The literal control character is not necessary, this works: `${filename%$'\r'}`